# MongoDB query show all value in array property when reference database

Tags: mongodb, reference, database

I cannot show all`, if some value are in array property in mongo document. For example, I have some collection users, and such document:

This is collection friend

```
'list': [
{
  '_id': '123',
  'name':'Charlie',
  'age':50,
},
{
  '_id': '234',
  'name':'Micheal',
  'age':32,
},
{
  '_id': '345',
  'name':'Alice',
  'age':45,
}
]
```

This is collection seft

```
'name':'Paul',
  'age':43,
  'friends': 
    [
        {  '$ref': 'friend',
           '$id': 123},
        {  '$ref': 'friend',
           '$id': 234},
        {  '$ref': 'friend',
           '$id': 345}
    ],
```

Now, let's suppose that I want to query "show all friends of Paul" like:

```
{
  'name':'Paul',
  'age':43,
  'friendsIDs': 
  'friends': 
    [
        {  '_id': '123',
           'name':'Charlie',
           'age':50 },
        {  '_id': '234',
           'name':'Micheal',
           'age':32},
        {  '_id': '345',
           'name':'Alice',
           'age':45 }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This needs to be done in your application layer, MongoDB doesn't support join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support joins. You can read more about that **[here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)**.

However, you can manually reproduce the same scenario you described above in MongoDB by using some native JavaScript functions to fill in the friends array with the references and save the modified data to another collection say `self_friends`.

Let's demonstrate this by using the above schema. Insert the sample data in two collections `self` and `friends`:

```
// Populate self collection
db.self.insert([
    {
        'name':'Paul',
        'age':43,
        'friends': 
        [
            {  '$ref': 'friend',
               '$id': 123},
            {  '$ref': 'friend',
               '$id': 234},
            {  '$ref': 'friend',
               '$id': 345}
        ]
    }    
]);

// Populate friends collection
db.friends.insert([
    {
      '_id': '123',
      'name':'Charlie',
      'age':50,
    },
    {
      '_id': '234',
      'name':'Micheal',
      'age':32,
    },
    {
      '_id': '345',
      'name':'Alice',
      'age':45,
    }
]);
```

The following operation will populate another collection `self_friends` with the desired result:

```
db.self.find({"name" : "Paul"}).forEach(function(doc){
        var friends = doc.friends.map(function(f){
            //var friend = db.friends.findOne({_id: f["$id"].toString()})
            // Or use @SylvainLeroux's brilliant suggestion 
            var friend = db.getCollection(f["$ref"]).findOne({_id: f["$id"].toString()})
            return friend;
        });
        doc.friends = friends;
        db.self_friends.save(doc);
})
```

Querying the `db.self_friends` collection with `db.self_friends.find()` will give the result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5549f2ff180e849972939047"),
    "name" : "Paul",
    "age" : 43,
    "friends" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "123",
            "name" : "Charlie",
            "age" : 50
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "234",
            "name" : "Micheal",
            "age" : 32
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "345",
            "name" : "Alice",
            "age" : 45
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Given the OP document stores DBRef, _maybe_ you should use something like `db.getCollection(f["$ref"]).findOne({_id: f["$id"].toString()})` -- that being said, I don't think there is any benefit in using DBRef here instead of plain id. Or is it ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux That's a great suggestion actually, would make much more sense to use the `$ref` key to get the collection with the value. I also would concur it wont be too beneficial to use DBRefs in the case above as the `_id`s are stored as strings in the reference collections.